# How to set HTML5 attributes like 'required' using a Slim template

Tags: html, forms, validation, slim-lang, required-field

I m laying out a form using the [Slim](http://slim-lang.com) template language and want to add the `required` attribute to my input.

```
input#first_name(required name="first_name" type="text" pattern="^[A-Z][a-z]+$")
```

However the HTML that is generated from this ends up being

```
 <input id="first_name" name="first_name" pattern="^[A-Z][a-z]+$" required="" type="text" />
```

And that's not what I need.

I've gone through the docs but can't see any way with Slim to add a standalone html5 attribute.

Likewise adding the `data-abide` attribute to the `form` tag (as required by the Zurb Foundation framework) fails.

```
form.custom(data-abide method="POST" action="/registration")
```

leads to

```
<form action="/registration" class="custom" data-abide="" method="POST">
```

Which the Zurb scripts ignore.

What am I missing?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/198)

Comment: No.  See https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/433

Comment: Actually [this answer](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/433#issuecomment-21923391) pretty much nails it. Apparently attribute="" is equivalent to the standalone attribute, so slim is correct. It seems to be a bug in the Zurb Foundation framework, or, more likely, some error in my own.

Comment: My solution has been to drop using Zurb Foundation and port my app to Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 4):

In your ***.html.slim** file do:

```
input#first_name required="" name="first_name" type="text" pattern="^[A-Z][a-z]+$"
```

*Note that empty attribute syntax:*

```
<input required>
```

Is equivalent to:

```
<input required="">
```

Answer (score 1):

More readable would be:

```
= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

= text_field_tag :user_name, "XYZ", readonly: true, required: true